# Object disposing in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for the right way to dispose objects in a Xamarin Forms application. Currently i'm using XAML and MVVM coding style. Then from my view model i get a reference to a disposable object through the builtin service locator ([DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/)). Ideally i should be able to call Dispose() on the objects from my view model, but other solutions like attaching to [ContentPage.OnDisappearing](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnDisappearing/) and [NavigationPage.Popped](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.Popped/) could be feasible.

Comment: Not really sure what question you are asking.  What is wrong with the suggestions you have already made?

Comment: I don't know how i should handle the disposal from the view model. The other two options are not that neat as the code is spread across different files and require additional coding.

Answer (score 13):

I had pretty much the same requirement a couple of weeks ago. I wanted to make sure that event subscriptions in my view models would be unsubscribed when the page is closed. After a lot of research my conclusion was that the simplest solution was to use the ContentPage.OnDisappearing method.

As you pointed out the object you want to dispose is in your ViewModel, so you need a little bit of infrastructure to make sure your ViewModel is informed when the it's disappearing. To do that I defined a base implementation of my view model that had two key methods OnAppearing and OnDisappearing (note this was a class rather than an interface because I have other base functionality such as IPropertyNotify implementation - not shown here).

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when page is appearing.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void OnAppearing()
    {
        // No default implementation. 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the view model is disappearing. View Model clean-up should be performed here.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void OnDisappearing()
    {
        // No default implementation. 
    }
}
```

Then I subsclassed ContentPage and override the OnAppearing and OnDisappearing methods and then use them to notify my view model.

```
public class PageBase : ContentPage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs page clean-up.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        var viewModel = BindingContext as ViewModelBase;

        // Inform the view model that it is disappearing so that it can remove event handlers
        // and perform any other clean-up required..
        viewModel?.OnDisappearing();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // Inform the view model that it is appearing
        var viewModel = BindingContext as ViewModelBase;

        // Inform the view model that it is appearing.
        viewModel?.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

Then when you implement a page just make sure that it is of type PageBase:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PageBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Forms.App.Controls;assembly=Forms.App"
          xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Forms.App.Converters;assembly=Forms.App"
          xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Forms.App.Pages;assembly=Forms.App"
          x:Class="Forms.App.Pages.LogonPage"
          NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
          Title="Logon">
```

And in your ViewModel you can then override your OnDisappearing method and dispose your objects:

```
public class FormViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        // Dispose whatever objects are neede here
    }
}
```

Just one thing to watch out for - if you're using stack navigation the OnDisappearing method gets called when you stack another page on-top of your current page (your page is disappearing temporarily after all). So you will need to cater for this and probably not dispose your object in that case. However if you're not stacking anything on-top of your page there is nothing to worry about. In my case it was just event subscriptions so I attached the event handlers in the OnAppearing and detached them on the OnDisappearing.

I hope that helps you out!

Comment: A really good solution. I think the only thing to be careful is the fact that you didn't call base.OnAppearing

Answer (score 6):

We were getting disposed of object exceptions in Forms when Bindings to ListViews or Labels changed values as pages/fragments were being disposed of. I'm assuming you could dispose of objects in your ViewModel the same place we were removing bindings.

```
protected override void OnParentSet()
{
    base.OnParentSet();

    if (Parent == null)
    {
        //Clear a bunch of bindings or dispose of ViewModel objects 
        BindingContext =
            _listView.ItemsSource = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it not better to set _listview= null;

Comment: I think that was the first thing I tried and it might work now with newer versions of Forms but at that time our game had some really complex ListViews inside of fragments, pages, and popups that were being kept in memory even when popped/removed from the stack and were not being gc until we cleared the bindings and ItemsSource.

Comment: parent is never set to null on a modal NavigationPage first page

Answer (score 2):

I have View Models that conform to IDisposable.  So I needed a way for the Page's BindingContext to be disposed when the page is no longer needed.

I used the suggestion of Nick which uses OnParentSet being set to NULL to known when the page is no longer needed.

The SafeContentPage class can be used in place of ContentPage.  Iff The binding context supports IDisposable will it automatically try to dispose the binding context.

```
public class SafeContentPage : ContentPage
{
    protected override void OnParentSet()
    {
        base.OnParentSet();
        if (Parent == null)
            DisposeBindingContext();
    }

    protected void DisposeBindingContext()
    {
        if (BindingContext is IDisposable disposableBindingContext) {
            disposableBindingContext.Dispose();
            BindingContext = null;
        }
    }

    ~SafeContentPage()
    {
        DisposeBindingContext();
    }
}
```

The OnDisappearing method isn't a reliable technique as there are platform differences in terms of when it is called, and just because the page disappeared doesn't mean its View Model is no longer needed.

Comment: The finalizer shouldn't call DisposeBindingContext. Only unmanaged resources should be released in the finalizer. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern)

Comment: Not sure where you get that from the article.  It explicitly gives an example of a finalizer calling dispose see the section on Finalizable Types.  "DO make a type finalizable if the type is responsible for releasing an unmanaged resource..."

Comment: The binding context is NOT an unmanaged resource. Finalizers would make sense on custom renderers or effects that handle unmanaged resources. i.e: an android bitmap that you handle natively.

Comment: To clarify, even if `disposableBindingContext` references an unmanaged resource (e.g. native bitmap), `disposableBindingContext` itself is still managed. The reason that SafeContentPage's finalizer shouldn't call `disposableBindingContext.Dispose` is that `disposableBindingContext` is required to have its own finalizer that will also run during GC to release the unmanaged resource.