# Best way to split huge view model/xaml

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, viewmodel

I’m refactoring a big view model and it's associated XAML page. I use Prism. The main page has a clear functionality, create an avatar. There are steps to create the avatar like take the picture, edit the picture, etc. I have now a detail side bar which controls the navigation for the steps and a main content area which I show different content depending on these steps. I hide/show the appropriate views depending on the step. The project grew and now I have a 2000+ line view model and a huge XAML file.

What I ended up doing after some research is creating ContentViews for each step (showing and hiding them for each step again), so the XAML get's modularized for each step and also a View Model for each step. I was successful in binding the ContentView to each ViewModel but now I have problems communicating the different View Models information.

As before everything was in the same View Model, all views could share the same bound properties if needed. Now, as each view model is independent I need to find a way to properly share this information. My first approach was to use the Messaging Center. This way I can send the information i need to share to the view model that manages the navigation between steps (NavigationViewModel) and this can send this information to the following view models.

The thing is that I don't really like this solution as I find it too complex and will end up with a lot of code in the NavigationViewModel to subscribe/send to each sub-viewmodel to pass the shared information.

So my question is, do you know any other way to ease the communication between the view models?

I even thought about using partial classes to 'hide' my big view model complexity, but I think this is not a good idea.

Comment: Probably need your code to make details comments, but you could Inject a singleton and maintain the state there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up doing what it was suggested in this answer successfuly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43539228/9395428

Comment: That's really good one.... i may use it as well!!!. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Recenlty i came across the same problem,my ViewModel became really huge(with hundreds of properties) .So what i did is :

1. Created an Interface class.Putting all the common properties in there.Let's say IA.
2. Created another class inheriting IA.

And now multiple classes are inherting IA,reducing the overall properties numbers.

Comment: Inheritance can help to a limit, but in my case it's not the amount of properties that need to be shared, but to modularise the functionality in different view models. As I said in a comment on my post, I used the solution suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538718/update-viewmodel-from-another-viewmodel-xamarin-forms/43539228#43539228
Thanks for the answer though