# Do View-ViewModel be dispose when navigate

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, prism, viewmodel

I'm working in a Xamarin Forms project, using Prism DryIoc.
For example, i have a `MainPage`, and a `APage`, with `ViewModels` `MainPageViewModel` and `APageViewModel`. In `APageViewModel` i have a timer as simple as the code below:

```
private Timer _timer;
public override void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.Initialize(parameters);

        _timer = new Timer(1000);

        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}: Timer run");
        };

        _timer.Start();
    }
```

When i navigate from MainPage to APage using `NavigationService.PushAsync`, the timer start. But when excute `NavigationService.GoBackAsync` from `APageViewModel`, the timer not stop if i dont manual stop the timer with `_timer.Stop()`. So i wonder if the `APageViewModel` being properly dispose to clear resources that being use in the view model?

Comment: What code do you expect to make the timer stop? None that you posted, and the framework cannot magically know that you started a timer, after all. If your view model implements `IDisposable` you should show that code, too.

Comment: I think you have to stop the timer manually as View-ViewModel won't be dispose when navigate back.

Comment: Stop timer is simple. But my question is, do object ViewModel being dispose to clear resources?

Comment: Have a look at these threads may help: [object-disposing-in-xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494527/object-disposing-in-xamarin-forms/43551679) and [viewmodel-lifecycle-when-does-it-get-disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961664/viewmodel-lifecycle-when-does-it-get-disposed).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT as far as I understand, if the view model implements `IDisposable`, Prism will call `Dispose`

Comment: @dienbien001 do you implement `IDisposable` or not?

Comment: @Haukinger yes, i do implemente `IDisposable`.

Comment: @dienbien001 and where's the code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is my code: https://github.com/dienbien001/AppPrismSample1/blob/master/AppPrismSample/AppPrismSample/ViewModels/APageViewModel.cs. Just call _timer.Stop() from Destroy method can stop the timer. But i wonder will the timer be clear from resource, or i have to call call `_timer = null` in Destroy method.

Comment: @Haukinger: I've just add IDisposable to ViewModel, but the Dispose not being called.

Comment: @dienbien001you can try to Implement IDestructible interface in APageViewModel and implement method Destroy...Later you can add debugger pointer to verify if Dispose was called or not

Comment: @HamidShaikh thanks you. That's the solution we're doing right now.

Comment: @dienbien001 Great, Please share result once you are done with your analysis

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to stop the timer on the OnDisappearing method of the page?

Comment: My question is not "how to stop timer", but do ViewModel object being disposed when navigate back to clear resources?